# MapKit : the setSelected(_:animated:) not called

Tags: ios, mapkit, selected

In the display map page, the `annotationview` is customized and I am overriding the`setSelected(:)`method in the implementation. However, when I click
`annotationView`, the method is not called.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select {
    [super setSelected:select];  
  
    NSLog(@"select:+++++ %d", select);
}
```

the `NSLog` not print, Why?

Answer (score 1):

### Direct Solution

If you only want a direct solution, this may help.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select { 
    [super setSelected:select animated:YES]
  
    NSLog(@"select:+++++ %d", select);
}
```

---

### Implementation

> I am overriding the `setSelected(_:animated:)` method in the implementation

If so, I think you should override below method rather than `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select`, which is the **Setter** method of property `selected`.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    .... // do your custom work
}
```

---

### Why and How

After testing a lot, I find that `Super Class` must implentation this

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    
}
```

So you will get nothing when calling `[super setSelected:select]`

It's weird but may be reasonable If Apple does not recommend us to override `selected`'s **Setter** method as `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select` already do the job.

As you can see, this method exist in the most of System Class.

Comment: I think you're right. I've also noticed this. I don't understand why the previous project personnel  override ```- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select``` this method. I think it's wrong